# Zeros of Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry, roots

I'm studying the function

$$ f(x) = \log(x + 1) + \cos(x)/2 $$

The first derivative is:

$$ f'(x) = 1/(x + 1) − \sin(x)/2. $$

To find the first two positive critical points (without Wolfram and the like), should I be using something like the Newton–Raphson  method (from a previous, similar problem: [Root of Logarithmic Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391980/root-of-logarithmic-equation)) or is there a simpler way, when dealing with trigonometric functions?

Comment: a short intro to root finding could be found here, hopefully helpful to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to use numerical methods here.  There is not likely to be a "closed-form" solution to $1/(x+1) + \sin(x)/2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Newton-Raphson would be a good way to go. As an experiment, it is also possible to solve the derivative for x and use that as a formula that would (hopefully) converge on an answer. For example,

$$\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{sin(x)}{2} = 0$$
$$\frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{sin(x)}{2}$$
$$x+1 = \frac{2}{sin(x)}$$
$$x = \frac{2}{sin(x)}-1$$

Therefore,

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{2}{sin(x_{n})}-1$$

This formula will yield approximately $1.17084752029579...$, but convergence is very slow, and it doesn't find the other roots. A slightly more sophisticated technique is preferable.